# publishing swf from air 2.6 player

Tags: actionscript-3

My game works with no error when i `control+enter` my `fla` file in `air 2.6` player.  my problem occurs when i open my `swf` file.

My `swf` file keeps iterating through timeline.  i have used `stop();` function in every timeframe.  this problem is not seen when i `control+enter` my fla.

I'm sorry if my question sounds stupid, but I'm really new to as3.

Comment: One thing to try. In your publish settings under the "Flash" tab make sure the "permit debugging" is checked, then publish, open the swf and see if there is an error that pops up. Sounds like your code is broken somewhere. Also check the output window in debug mode for any errors or wanrings.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have opened the `swf` file, and not the `.exe` file genereated after you publish the air app. Publish the application, and then install it. After this you should be able to run it by opening the `.exe` file.

When you debug an air application, the swf file is not run in the flash player, rather it is run in the Air Debug Launcher. This program also reads the other files associated with your application, namely the `...-app.xml` file.